# Do some mail servers rewrite envelope-to in response to a CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, cname-record, email-server

In DNS, I have `service.example.com. CNAME box.example.com.`  When sending email automatically to about 10,000 adresses (no worries, nothing sinister), I set envelope-from to `something@service.example.com`.  Of the bounces that come back, about 70% have envelope-to set to `something@service.example.com` (which is what I would expect), but about 30% have envelope-to to `something@box.example.com`.

What is going on here?  Do some MTAs change envelope-to when they discover a CNAME?  Which MTAs?

Is it a good idea to use an A record instead of a CNAME for `service.example.com.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some MTA rewrite addresses, usually sendmail with custom macros that are trying to consolidate multiple internal (formerly external) domains into one consistent external domain.

Your bounce percentages might also be explained by the level at which the bounce came back. For example, a bounce from your edge MTA might well look different than a bounce from someone else's MTA.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for the exact performance in your situation due to lack of details.

The `Return-Path:` header is specified by the MDA, which uses the address identified in the `MAIL FROM` command.

The MTA typically defaults the `MAIL FROM` as the user sending the mail.  For example, calling `qmail-inject` with the `-f` flag can change the `Return-Path` to the specified e-Mail address.

For example, my username is warner on the awesomebox(.awesomedomain.org) server.  If I send an e-Mail using mutt and specify the `From:` header as warner@awesomedomain.org, the MTA (QMAIL) is going to default to specifying the `MAIL FROM` as warner@awesomebox.awesomedomain.org.

The same performance would apply to CGI running via Apache, it would default the `Return-Path` to the user Apache runs as.

Answer (score -1):

According to RFC 1123 your MX record **must** point to a hostname with an A record (and/or AAAA for IPv6), and **never** to one with a CNAME!

Comment: There is no MX record involved here, only a CNAME (service.example.com) pointing to an A record (box.example.com).

Comment: Well, you **must** have an MX record.  There is an old RFC that states that in absence of an MX record the A record should be used instead, but that was only meant as a temporary fallback until all admins had implemented the MX record, and in both cases it specifically asks for a canonical hostname (so no CNAME).  (Some anti-spam systems probably give mail from your server a negative marking for the fact that you don't have an MX record, and a second one for only having a CNAME...)

Comment: So to answer your question: make an MX record that points to a hostname with an A record.  The hostname can be whatever mailserver you want to use to receive mail for `@service.example.com` (and of course, the mailserver must also be configured to accept mail for that domain).